# Some fields not copying across attribute tables using QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have only recently started using QGIS for a work project, and have encountered an issue when copying polygons from one layer to another. The first layer contains a unique field identifier and many other columns including one with text (style_description):

[image]

In the destination layer, I have created a new attributes table with the ogc_fid column and this is populated whenever I copy a polygon. However, the issue I am encountering is that there is a limit to the characters when creating a new column and can only create one called 'style_desc' and the fields are not populated when copying a polygon.

[image]

Comment: I would guess the layer you are copying into is a shapefile? In which case, the field name is limited to 10 characters. I would recommend using the GeoPackage format, [for many reasons](https://www.gis-blog.com/geopackage-vs-shapefile/).

Comment: QGIS will only copy attributes if it finds a matching field. style_description is not the same as style_desc. You could rename your source field to match and then copy.

Comment: Thanks. I think renaming the fields is the best way forward.